# Firebase Authentication Error: I Enabled the Email/Password option

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to login to Firebase with Android, I'm getting strange messages:

[Code Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1bHhL.png)

```
login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            final String Email,Pass;
            Email=email.getText().toString();
            Pass=pass.getText().toString();
            if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(Email) && !TextUtils.isEmpty(Pass))
            {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                if(Pass.length()>=6)
                {
                    auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
                    auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(Email, Pass).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task)
                        {
                            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                            if (task.isSuccessful())
                            {
                                Intent i = new Intent(login.this, MainActivity.class);
                                i.putExtra("Email",Email);
                                startActivity(i);
                                finish();
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                                Toast.makeText(login.this, "" + task.getException(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
                else
                {
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    Toast.makeText(login.this, "Password Must be 8 Character Long", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

            }
            else
            {
                progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(login.this, "Provide Email and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
```

> build.Gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.butt************"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner 

    "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }
        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
        implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
        implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
        compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
        androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
        implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.1'
        apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
        implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'


    }
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

With the Error Message:

> W/BiChannelGoogleApi: [FirebaseAuth: ] getGoogleApiForMethod()
>   returned Gms
>       D/ViewRootImpl: Buffer Count from app info with  ::-1 && -1 for :: 
>       com.butt.mediacalradar from View :: -1 DBQ Enabled ::false false

```
"com.google.firebase.FirebaseException. An internal Error Occur [Bad Request]".
```

> After Updating

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com**********"
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    //compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:gridlayout-v7:27.0.1'
    apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'


}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: Can you post the Java code that produced these exceptions?  We can't help you without seeing your code.  You can edit your own question, then add the Java code there.

Comment: Please add the corresponding code.

Comment: @AlexMamo Code Added

Comment: Your code looks good. Please also add your `build.gradle` file.

Comment: @AlexMamo also added build.gradle

Answer (score 0):

In order to make it work, please use the last versions for all your dependencies:

First change google services version (build.gradle Project) to:

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.0.1'
```

And the dependencies from:

```
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.8.0'
```

to

```
//compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'
```

As you can see, the first line is commented. Don't also forget to delete the duplicate `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`. Should remain only at the end of the file.

Comment: getting error in these two libraries >compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'  and implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.1'

Comment: As I said `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:11.8.0'` must be removed or commented. And what is the error in the for the second? We are close.

Comment: by mistake i put the classpatch to app module gradel but now that error is corrected .should i change from classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'  to 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.1'

Comment: You should use the latest version. Does it work now?

Comment: it says all gms/firebase libraries must use exact same version specification

Comment: Can you please share again your changed file?

Comment: added the changed gradle file

Comment: Remove this line `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` from the dependencies (should remain only as the last line in the file) and change this: `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'` to `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'`. What is the result?

Comment: And you haven't added `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.0'`  as in my answer. It's mandatory now to have it.

Comment: added  that one but still getting same message An interal error Occur [Bad Request]

Comment: Please paste here the enitire error and the line at which it occurs.

Comment: i updated my Android Studio and apply your guidance and there is no error shown but it is no allowing to login through auth and giving thesame error on runtime " An Internal error Occur [BadRequest]

Comment: Alex play services latest version on my device is 12 but in firebase prerequisites google play services version is 15.0.0 or heigher. is it causing the problem ??

Comment: Yes, you should have the same versions. Please update the google play services version on your device to the latest one.

Comment: the latest version on play store is 12. something